# How to add a record whilst passing its primary key id as an argument into another record

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

A "Add Account" button essentially creates a new **account** and **transaction** record in their respective database (using Kotlin Flow), where the common variable between the two database is the *account id*. A variable that is a primary key in the **account** database, and an integer column in the **transaction**.

I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the *account id* since it is only created once the new account record.

onClick:

```
accountVM.addAccount(Account(accountName))
accountVM.getLatestAccount()
transactionVM.addTransaction(Transaction(accountVM.account.accountId, trnxAmount)
```

AccountVM:

```
    var account by mutableStateOf(
        Pool("")
    )

    fun addAccount(account: Account) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.addAccountRepo(account).collect {
            account = it
        }
    } }

    fun getLatestAccount() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.getLatestAccountRepo()
    } }
```

transactionVM:

```
    fun addTransaction(transaction: Transaction) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.addTransactionRepo(transaction)
    } }
```

Problem with this approach is the *accountVM.account.accountId* is not updated during the onClick, hence the *account id* was never passed.

Answer (score 0):

Managed a solution

Under accountVM:

```
var account by mutableStateOf(
Pool("")


fun addAccount(account: Account, trnxAmount: Double) {
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repository.addAccountRepo(account)
    repository.getLatestAccountRepo().collect { account ->
        transactionRepository.addTransactionRepo(
            Transaction(account.accountId, trnxAmount)
        )
    }
} }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).